How to convert a set of first order DEs to a single higher order DE
I'm wondering how to convert a set of first order DEs into just a single DE. I've been looking at this for a while and I can't figure it out. I understand the opposite direction, a single DE into a system of first order but I just can't figure this out. Specifically I'm looking at this system.
$$x'_1 = -0.313x_1+56.7x_2+0.232u$$
$$x'_2 = -0.0139x_1-0.426x_2+0.0203u$$
$$x'_3 = 56.7x_2$$
Where u and x are functions of time.

Hint: Go through each line and take derivatives, then combine.

I was working in that direction but I'm still confused. If I take the derivative of the third equation then work back towards the first, I get an answer that doesn't make sense to me. I got x1'=-1.2688x3'''-30.647x2'+1.4604u'. I don't think this is right and I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks for your response.

Is $u$ the unit step function?

The first two equations have the form
\begin{align}
x_1'&=ax_1+bx_2+cu, \tag{1} \\
x_2'&=dx_1+ex_2+fu. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Differentiate $(1)$ and use $(2)$ to eliminate $x_2'$:
$$
x_1''=ax_1'+bx_2'+cu'=ax_1'+b(dx_1+ex_2+fu)+cu'. \tag{3}
$$
Now use $(1)$ to eliminate $x_2$ from $(3)$:
$$
x_1''=ax_1'+b(dx_1+fu)+e(x_1'-ax_1-cu)+cu'. \tag{4}
$$
After solving $(4)$, you can again use $(1)$ to find $x_2$,
$$
x_2=\frac{1}{b}(x_1'-ax_1-cu), \tag{5}
$$
and, finally, solve $x_3'=56.7x_2$ to obtain $x_3$.

For a linear differential equation
$$\dot x = A x$$
$A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$,  each component $x_k$ of a solution $x\colon I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $P(\frac{d}{d t}) x_k = 0$, where $P= P_A(\cdot)$ is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$.
